# How to tune down the Hyperic built-in postgresql database for a small setup

Tags: postgresql, performance-tuning, small-business, hyperic

We are testing out Hyperic 4.5.1 in a quite small environment for now. Currently there are just 1-5 agents and there probably won't be any more than 10-15.

When I run `ps ax` there are 20(!) postgres processes running. For a small setup like this, that can't be necessary, can it? I'm a software developer and don't have much experience with setting up servers and such though, so don't really know.

Either way, what settings are appropriate for a small Hyperic setup like this?

---

**Current**, default and untouched **configuration file**, hqdb/data/postgresql.conf:

```
# -----------------------------
# PostgreSQL configuration file
# -----------------------------
#
# This file consists of lines of the form:
#
#   name = value
#
# (The '=' is optional.)  White space may be used.  Comments are introduced
# with '#' anywhere on a line.  The complete list of option names and
# allowed values can be found in the PostgreSQL documentation.  The
# commented-out settings shown in this file represent the default values.
#
# Please note that re-commenting a setting is NOT sufficient to revert it
# to the default value, unless you restart the server.
#
# Any option can also be given as a command line switch to the server,
# e.g., 'postgres -c log_connections=on'.  Some options can be changed at
# run-time with the 'SET' SQL command.
#
# This file is read on server startup and when the server receives a
# SIGHUP.  If you edit the file on a running system, you have to SIGHUP the
# server for the changes to take effect, or use "pg_ctl reload". Some
# settings, which are marked below, require a server shutdown and restart
# to take effect.
#
# Memory units:  kB = kilobytes MB = megabytes GB = gigabytes
# Time units:    ms = milliseconds s = seconds min = minutes h = hours d = days


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# FILE LOCATIONS
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# The default values of these variables are driven from the -D command line
# switch or PGDATA environment variable, represented here as ConfigDir.

#data_directory = 'ConfigDir'       # use data in another directory
                    # (change requires restart)
#hba_file = 'ConfigDir/pg_hba.conf' # host-based authentication file
                    # (change requires restart)
#ident_file = 'ConfigDir/pg_ident.conf' # ident configuration file
                    # (change requires restart)

# If external_pid_file is not explicitly set, no extra PID file is written.
#external_pid_file = '(none)'       # write an extra PID file
                    # (change requires restart)


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

#listen_addresses = 'localhost'     # what IP address(es) to listen on; 
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost', '*' = all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 9432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
# Note: increasing max_connections costs ~400 bytes of shared memory per 
# connection slot, plus lock space (see max_locks_per_transaction).  You
# might also need to raise shared_buffers to support more connections.
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directory = ''     # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # octal
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                    # (change requires restart)

# - Security & Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min      # 1s-600s
#ssl = off              # (change requires restart)
#password_encryption = on
#db_user_namespace = off

# Kerberos
#krb_server_keyfile = ''        # (change requires restart)
#krb_srvname = 'postgres'       # (change requires restart)
#krb_server_hostname = ''       # empty string matches any keytab entry
                    # (change requires restart)
#krb_caseins_users = off        # (change requires restart)

# - TCP Keepalives -
# see 'man 7 tcp' for details

#tcp_keepalives_idle = 0        # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_interval = 0        # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_count = 0       # TCP_KEEPCNT;
                    # 0 selects the system default


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RESOURCE USAGE (except WAL)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Memory -

shared_buffers = 64MB           # min 128kB or max_connections*16kB
                    # (change requires restart)
#temp_buffers = 8MB         # min 800kB
#max_prepared_transactions = 5      # can be 0 or more
                    # (change requires restart)
# Note: increasing max_prepared_transactions costs ~600 bytes of shared memory
# per transaction slot, plus lock space (see max_locks_per_transaction).
work_mem = 2MB              # min 64kB
maintenance_work_mem = 32MB     # min 1MB
#max_stack_depth = 2MB          # min 100kB

# - Free Space Map -

max_fsm_pages = 204800              # min max_fsm_relations*16, 6 bytes each
                    # (change requires restart)
#max_fsm_relations = 1000       # min 100, ~70 bytes each
                    # (change requires restart)

# - Kernel Resource Usage -

#max_files_per_process = 1000       # min 25
                    # (change requires restart)
#shared_preload_libraries = ''      # (change requires restart)

# - Cost-Based Vacuum Delay -

#vacuum_cost_delay = 0          # 0-1000 milliseconds
#vacuum_cost_page_hit = 1       # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_page_miss = 10     # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_page_dirty = 20        # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_limit = 200        # 0-10000 credits

# - Background writer -

#bgwriter_delay = 200ms         # 10-10000ms between rounds
#bgwriter_lru_percent = 1.0     # 0-100% of LRU buffers scanned/round
#bgwriter_lru_maxpages = 5      # 0-1000 buffers max written/round
#bgwriter_all_percent = 0.333       # 0-100% of all buffers scanned/round
#bgwriter_all_maxpages = 5      # 0-1000 buffers max written/round


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WRITE AHEAD LOG
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Settings -

fsync = on              # turns forced synchronization on or off
#wal_sync_method = fsync        # the default is the first option 
                    # supported by the operating system:
                    #   open_datasync
                    #   fdatasync
                    #   fsync
                    #   fsync_writethrough
                    #   open_sync
#full_page_writes = on          # recover from partial page writes
#wal_buffers = 64kB         # min 32kB
                    # (change requires restart)
commit_delay = 100000           # range 0-100000, in microseconds
#commit_siblings = 5            # range 1-1000

# - Checkpoints -

checkpoint_segments = 10        # in logfile segments, min 1, 16MB each
#checkpoint_timeout = 5min      # range 30s-1h
#checkpoint_warning = 30s       # 0 is off

# - Archiving -

#archive_command = ''       # command to use to archive a logfile segment
#archive_timeout = 0        # force a logfile segment switch after this
                # many seconds; 0 is off


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# QUERY TUNING
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Planner Method Configuration -

#enable_bitmapscan = on
#enable_hashagg = on
#enable_hashjoin = on
#enable_indexscan = on
#enable_mergejoin = on
#enable_nestloop = on
#enable_seqscan = on
#enable_sort = on
#enable_tidscan = on

# - Planner Cost Constants -

#seq_page_cost = 1.0            # measured on an arbitrary scale
#random_page_cost = 4.0         # same scale as above
#cpu_tuple_cost = 0.01          # same scale as above
#cpu_index_tuple_cost = 0.005       # same scale as above
#cpu_operator_cost = 0.0025     # same scale as above
#effective_cache_size = 128MB

# - Genetic Query Optimizer -

#geqo = on
#geqo_threshold = 12
#geqo_effort = 5            # range 1-10
#geqo_pool_size = 0         # selects default based on effort
#geqo_generations = 0           # selects default based on effort
#geqo_selection_bias = 2.0      # range 1.5-2.0

# - Other Planner Options -

#default_statistics_target = 10     # range 1-1000
#constraint_exclusion = off
#from_collapse_limit = 8
#join_collapse_limit = 8        # 1 disables collapsing of explicit 
                    # JOINs


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ERROR REPORTING AND LOGGING
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Where to Log -

log_destination = 'stderr'      # Valid values are combinations of 
                    # stderr, syslog and eventlog, 
                    # depending on platform.

# This is used when logging to stderr:
redirect_stderr = on            # Enable capturing of stderr into log 
                    # files
                    # (change requires restart)

# These are only used if redirect_stderr is on:
log_directory = '../../logs'        # Directory where log files are written
                    # Can be absolute or relative to PGDATA
log_filename = 'hqdb-%Y-%m-%d.log'      # Log file name pattern.
                    # Can include strftime() escapes
#log_truncate_on_rotation = off # If on, any existing log file of the same 
                    # name as the new log file will be
                    # truncated rather than appended to. But
                    # such truncation only occurs on
                    # time-driven rotation, not on restarts
                    # or size-driven rotation. Default is
                    # off, meaning append to existing files
                    # in all cases.
log_rotation_age = 1d           # Automatic rotation of logfiles will 
                    # happen after that time.  0 to 
                    # disable.
#log_rotation_size = 10MB       # Automatic rotation of logfiles will 
                    # happen after that much log
                    # output.  0 to disable.

# These are relevant when logging to syslog:
#syslog_facility = 'LOCAL0'
#syslog_ident = 'postgres'


# - When to Log -

#client_min_messages = notice       # Values, in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   log
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error

#log_min_messages = notice      # Values, in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   info
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
                    #   log
                    #   fatal
                    #   panic

#log_error_verbosity = default      # terse, default, or verbose messages

#log_min_error_statement = error    # Values in order of increasing severity:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   info
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
                    #   fatal
                    #   panic (effectively off)

log_min_duration_statement = 10000  # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements
                    # and their durations.

#silent_mode = off          # DO NOT USE without syslog or 
                    # redirect_stderr
                    # (change requires restart)

# - What to Log -

#debug_print_parse = off
#debug_print_rewritten = off
#debug_print_plan = off
#debug_pretty_print = off
#log_connections = off
#log_disconnections = off
#log_duration = off
#log_line_prefix = ''           # Special values:
                    #   %u = user name
                    #   %d = database name
                    #   %r = remote host and port
                    #   %h = remote host
                    #   %p = PID
                    #   %t = timestamp (no milliseconds)
                    #   %m = timestamp with milliseconds
                    #   %i = command tag
                    #   %c = session id
                    #   %l = session line number
                    #   %s = session start timestamp
                    #   %x = transaction id
                    #   %q = stop here in non-session 
                    #        processes
                    #   %% = '%'
                    # e.g. '<%u%%%d> '
#log_statement = 'none'         # none, ddl, mod, all
#log_hostname = off


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RUNTIME STATISTICS
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Query/Index Statistics Collector -

#stats_command_string = on
#update_process_title = on

stats_start_collector = on      # needed for block or row stats
                    # (change requires restart)
stats_block_level = on
stats_row_level = on
stats_reset_on_server_start = off   # (change requires restart)


# - Statistics Monitoring -

#log_parser_stats = off
#log_planner_stats = off
#log_executor_stats = off
#log_statement_stats = off


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# AUTOVACUUM PARAMETERS
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#autovacuum = off           # enable autovacuum subprocess?
                    # 'on' requires stats_start_collector
                    # and stats_row_level to also be on
#autovacuum_naptime = 1min      # time between autovacuum runs
#autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 500  # min # of tuple updates before
                    # vacuum
#autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 250 # min # of tuple updates before 
                    # analyze
#autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.2   # fraction of rel size before 
                    # vacuum
#autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1  # fraction of rel size before 
                    # analyze
#autovacuum_freeze_max_age = 200000000  # maximum XID age before forced vacuum
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = -1  # default vacuum cost delay for 
                    # autovacuum, -1 means use 
                    # vacuum_cost_delay
#autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = -1  # default vacuum cost limit for 
                    # autovacuum, -1 means use
                    # vacuum_cost_limit


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CLIENT CONNECTION DEFAULTS
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Statement Behavior -

#search_path = '"$user",public'     # schema names
#default_tablespace = ''        # a tablespace name, '' uses
                    # the default
#check_function_bodies = on
#default_transaction_isolation = 'read committed'
#default_transaction_read_only = off
#statement_timeout = 0          # 0 is disabled
#vacuum_freeze_min_age = 100000000

# - Locale and Formatting -

datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
#timezone = unknown         # actually, defaults to TZ 
                    # environment setting
#timezone_abbreviations = 'Default'     # select the set of available timezone
                    # abbreviations. Currently, there are
                    #   Default
                    #   Australia
                    #   India
                    # However you can also create your own
                    # file in share/timezonesets/.
#extra_float_digits = 0         # min -15, max 2
#client_encoding = sql_ascii        # actually, defaults to database
                    # encoding

# These settings are initialized by initdb -- they might be changed
lc_messages = 'C'           # locale for system error message 
                    # strings
lc_monetary = 'C'           # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'C'            # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'C'               # locale for time formatting

# - Other Defaults -

#explain_pretty_print = on
#dynamic_library_path = '$libdir'
#local_preload_libraries = ''


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOCK MANAGEMENT
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#deadlock_timeout = 1s
#max_locks_per_transaction = 64     # min 10
                    # (change requires restart)
# Note: each lock table slot uses ~270 bytes of shared memory, and there are
# max_locks_per_transaction * (max_connections + max_prepared_transactions)
# lock table slots.


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# VERSION/PLATFORM COMPATIBILITY
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Previous Postgres Versions -

#add_missing_from = off
#array_nulls = on
#backslash_quote = safe_encoding    # on, off, or safe_encoding
#default_with_oids = off
#escape_string_warning = on
#standard_conforming_strings = off
#regex_flavor = advanced        # advanced, extended, or basic
#sql_inheritance = on

# - Other Platforms & Clients -

#transform_null_equals = off


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CUSTOMIZED OPTIONS
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#custom_variable_classes = ''       # list of custom variable class names
```

---

**SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;**

```
 datid | datname | procpid | usesysid | usename |          current_query          | waiting |          query_start          |         backend_start         | client_addr | client_port 
-------+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------+-------------
 16384 | hqdb    |    3267 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.036781+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.02413+01  | 127.0.0.1   |       47892
 16384 | hqdb    |    3268 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.050994+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.047393+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47893
 16384 | hqdb    |    3269 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.056661+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.053201+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47894
 16384 | hqdb    |    3271 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.062351+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.058822+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47895
 16384 | hqdb    |    3272 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.068328+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.064517+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47896
 16384 | hqdb    |    3273 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.07444+01  | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.070755+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47897
 16384 | hqdb    |    3274 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.080941+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.076983+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47898
 16384 | hqdb    |    3275 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.08741+01  | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.083697+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47899
 16384 | hqdb    |    3276 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.093597+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.089977+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47900
 16384 | hqdb    |    3277 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE> in transaction           | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.133974+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:20.096149+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47901
 16384 | hqdb    |    3308 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-09 10:49:27.402197+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:29.826321+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47902
 16384 | hqdb    |    3309 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:55.572395+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:29.865243+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47903
 16384 | hqdb    |    3310 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:55.586273+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:29.874346+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47904
 16384 | hqdb    |    3311 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-09 10:10:03.024088+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:29.883598+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47905
 16384 | hqdb    |    3312 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE> in transaction           | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:35.804457+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:29.892925+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47906
 16384 | hqdb    |    3418 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:55.580207+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:55.56911+01  | 127.0.0.1   |       47910
 16384 | hqdb    |    3419 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:55.59781+01  | 2011-02-08 15:51:55.588609+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47911
 16384 | hqdb    |    3422 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-09 10:10:02.668836+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:55.603076+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47914
 16384 | hqdb    |    3421 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:55.770427+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:55.603086+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47913
 16384 | hqdb    |    3420 |       10 | hqadmin | <IDLE>                          | f       | 2011-02-08 15:51:55.680785+01 | 2011-02-08 15:51:55.637058+01 | 127.0.0.1   |       47912
 16384 | hqdb    |   18233 |       10 | hqadmin | SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity; | f       | 2011-02-09 10:49:29.688949+01 | 2011-02-09 10:48:13.031475+01 |             |          -1
(21 rows)
```

Comment: add "SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;" output

Answer (score 1):

I would just go with what the server defaults are.  Those processes aren't really doing anything, and they don't take up too much memory.  Its good to have them there for when Hyperic gets cranked up, especially in the early discovery phases.

Answer (score 0):

This is IDLE connection. Try change "[Min/Max Idle Connections](http://support.hyperic.com/display/EVO/ui-tcserver.ServerJDBCRef)" to 0.

Comment: Where do I set this?

Comment: http://support.hyperic.com/display/EVO/ui-tcserver.ServerConfiguration#ui-tcserver.ServerConfiguration-jdbc

Comment: I'm probably blind and stupid, but I just can't find where to set this option. What configuration file do I set it in? Or is it through the gui? If through the gui, where? I have been at Administration -> HQ Server Settings, but can't find much there.